# Проблема в экспорте react-routera

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Помогите пожалуйста. Новичок в программировании. Вот мой код:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Router, Route, hashHistory} from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}/>
  </Router>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Но он выдает вот такую ошибку:

> ./src/index.js Attempted import error: 'hashHistory' is not exported
>   from 'react-router'.

Что я делаю не так? Вот код из app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Main from './mainPage/main';
// import Office from './office/office';
import './App.css';
import './body.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div class='wrapper'>

      {/* <Office /> */}
      <Main />
    </div>
   );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Скинул роутер с 5.0.1 до 3-ей версии и все заработало (npm install react-router@3).

Answer (score 3):

`hashHistory` был перенесен в `4` версии пакета из [`react-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) в новый пакет - [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) поэтому в `3` версии он еще работает. Ссылка на issue: [hashHistory stopped working in 4.0.0](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4752)

Установите новый пакет и следуйте новой документации для [HashRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md), должно получиться как-то так:

```
import { Route, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<HashRouter>
  <Route path='/' component={App}/>
</HashRouter>
```

Либо можно сделать так (документация по [Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Router.md)) если нужна `history` (которая `browserHistory`):

```
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <Route path='/' component={App}/>
</Router>
```

P.S.: *у `<Route>` есть атрибут `exact`, он используется в  `<Route>`, чтобы сказать данный `<Route>` работает только если URL на браузере абсолютно подходит значению атрибута его `path`.*

Для браузерных проектов есть `BrowserRouter` и `HashRouter` компоненты. `BrowserRouter` — следует использовать когда вы обрабатываете на сервере динамические запросы, а `HashRouter` используйте когда у вас статический веб сайт. Исходя из этого нужно делать выбор какой тип роутера использовать в своем приложении.

Обычно предпочтительнее использовать `BrowserRouter`, но если ваш сайт расположен на статическом сервере, то использовать `HashRouter` - это хорошее решение проблемы.

Хорошие ссылки:

- [HashRouter vs BrowserRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976069/5275890)
- [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)
- [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

Answer (score 0):

Скинул роутер с 5.0.1 до 3-ей версии:

```
npm install react-router@3
```

и все заработало.